# How do I fix Samsung Galaxy S5 FREEZING after updating to Android 5.1.1 Lollipop?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5, samsung-touchwiz

How do I fix the Samsung Galaxy S5 FREEZING AFTER UPDATING TO ANDROID 5.1.1 Lollipop? Ever since I installed 5.1.1 my phone locks up. It's like Samsung engineers purposefully sabotaged this update to force people to get the newest Samsung phone. The freezing happens several times a day with lots of lag. Facebook screen goes black, the keyboard takes a long time to pop-up, and words take a long time to show up after I type them across many different applications. I’ve rebooted my phone and cleared the cache several times. I had no freezing or lag issues before the update. This phone on paper is faster than the OnePlus One but is actually slower than it now. I am unable to root this S5 phone because Samsung's Knox security will be tripped.

I've taken the following steps to clear the system cache with no success:

- Turn the phone off.
- Press and hold the following buttons together: Power, Volume Up and Home.
- Release the buttons once the Android system recovery menu appears.
- Use the Volume buttons to navigate to Wipe Cache Partition option.
- Press the Power button to confirm selection.
- Select Reboot System Now option after deleting the cache.
- Wait for the phone to reboot.

Should I just sell it on ebay? lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always download the official earlier OS from Sammobile, and flash it using Odin. Since it's an official ROM, the Knox shouldn't be tripped.